# How might microscopic humanoids contain electricity?

Tags: energy

In my world, there are a race of microscopic humanoid organisms (0.3 mm - 0.33 mm). They live in a variety of biomes, such as leaf litter, stone and on plants and trees. In terms of technological advancement, they are near the bronze age and merely need to find/discover metal. They have domesticated pseudoscorpions, aphids, spider mites and white flies. Being in number 860,000 strong, they can mass produce "spider" silk, and have spears (for poking, not throwing), stone "swords". They have silk armor, chariots (sleds) pulled by pseudoscorpions and they can produce vinegar, formaldehyde, atropine and nicotine, although not in extremely great quantities. Most importantly, they can produce and conduct static electricity. My questions are:

1. How might such a civilization (lacking metal) store electricity
   for later use?
2. Can an electric motor exist on such a scale without
   metal?

Comment: How are they *generating* or capturing electricity? It seems to me like you need to answer that question before you consider how to *store* electricity. Also remember that an electric motor and a generator are really the same thing, only wired in reverse.

Comment: Note: watch out for the breakdown voltage of air, 3MV/m.  For a "handheld" device that's 0.05mm long, the maximum voltage is 150V.  Sharp corners can achieve that sort of voltage surprisingly quickly, so you'll want to make sure they only use smooth shapes

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, he is talking about static electricity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you say they can conduct electricity and they can produce it. So in a way they must have a sort of electrical conductor... they don’t know metal so let's say that they know graphite? Buckminsterfullerene? Anyway, the first Leyden jars didn’t use foil but just water, they would still have something metallic like a nail but let's say that you substitute that with graphite... (even a wick made of spider silk could work maybe? Never tried;) silk is a bad conductor by itself so you have to rely on soaking it with something) They have vinegar etc, better conductors than water to use in the primitive Leyden jar. Basically it's a primitive capacitor as storage.

Production: a friction machine probably they got there already since you say they can produce it.

Motor? Really don't think so.

What is not clear to me is how these guys, that must have stumbled on it by chance, would figure out they can store electricity (or even that they *should* store it for later use or figure out that they can build a motor to use it) but not know metals yet...

Comment: By nature of their small size and religious beliefs , the have an advanced understanding of Chemistry/biochemistry . The issue is that they cannot produce fire for the same reasons , and the highest amount of heat they can produce is around 200 degrees . since they lack the ability to produce a sufficient amount of heat , they cannot separate metals from non-metals

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn, sorry i might be confusing things but IMHO if they an advanced understanding of chemistry it seems improbable they dont know fire... unless you mean that is against their religion... And smelting through induction wouldn't be possible either because you cant refine metals that way and they would still be skipping the fire step... and static electricity wouldnt work for that Im afraid... they might be stuck...

Comment: No , what I mean is that fire can not exist at such a small size ,

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn, from what I know fire looks like glowing gas even under a microscope but i might be wrong. I do think that at one point you need to take some small liberties, they are microscopic people running around on sleds after all...